# Any alternative to XTerm with splitting and tabs?

Tags: xterm, tabs, split

XTerm is great because I can view images inside it in `w3m` or `ranger`. However, as a terminal it does not support tabs or splitting. Is there an alternative that works like XTerm but supports splitting and tabs?

Comment: How did you accomplish that? `w3m` and `ranger` open external programs for viewing images for me.

Comment: @muru: Follow these steps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJhDMxMgzC0

Comment: Interesting. Terminator, the obvious suggestion, doesn't support this yet. I'd guess Final Term might, but Final Term is not quite there yet in terms of other necessary features.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Is Putty Connection Manager available for Ubuntu? ;-)

Comment: @Ashwin I think I copied the wrong link :D puttycm seems dead too

Answer (score 7):

Do `sudo apt-get install suckless-tools`, then run this command to have a tabbed xterm:

```
tabbed -c xterm -into &
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a new tab and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to close a tab. You'll find more info in the man page for `tabbed`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **tilix** in **ubuntu .**

To install Tilix in Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10, 17.04 and 17.10 / Linux Mint 18.x, you can use the WebUpd8 Tilix PPA. To add the PPA and install Tilix, use the following commands:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/terminix
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt install tilix